# Compress the header size ios

Tags: ios, xcode

Hi i am getting header size 18k of encoded string.So i want to decrease size.I am compressing this in the form of nsdata. After compressing this i am converting this data into string.Getting the form of 
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

This is not giving correct answer.Could anyone help on this please.

Comment: You need to add a language tag. Header of what? to/from what? What is the compress/decompress code?

Comment: How do you convert data to string? This looks like base64 encoded